# I want a procedure to be executed when Oracle starts

Tags: oracle, startup

When I startup my Oracle instance, is it possible to get Oracle to run some PL/SQL during the initialization?

I have tried to find something on the web but my searches have not been fruitful.

More specifically,

If I issue

```
$ sqlplus ....
startup mount;
alter database open;
```

Can I get it to then run a PL/SQL procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for an AFTER STARTUP trigger.

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_on_open_trigger
AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
BEGIN
     <<< DO SOMETHING >>>
END my_on_open_trigger;
/
```

Comment: I will give that a go in the morning when I am at work

Comment: great. I used this before PDB state was stored to open all PDBs when the db started up.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple "after startup" triggers?

Comment: I just made 3 to test it and they all created. why not fold the logic into 1 ?

Comment: Just thinking that I am not the sole developer. Also can one define the order of the triggers

Comment: I don't think the order can be set which is very real reason to fold into 1 if possible.

Comment: Perhaps have one and have a table of code and use `exec immediate`?!

Comment: That would do it. just obviously with exec immediate beware sql injection.

Comment: I understand - but that table will be under our control. Just to get background processes up an running, going some maintenance etc

Comment: Great just feel obligated to mention :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kris Rice said (while discussing triggers' firing order in comments):

> I don't think the order can be set which is very real reason to fold
>   into 1 if possible

You think wrong :)

Since Oracle 11g, there's the FOLLOWS option which enables you to set such a thing. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger t1
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_Line('trigger 1');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger t2
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4    follows t3
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_Line('trigger 2');
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> create or replace trigger t3
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4    follows t1
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_Line('trigger 3');
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test values ('A');
trigger 1
trigger 3
trigger 2

1 row created.

SQL>
```

A side note: trigger T2 was created with errors as I said that it follows T3 which doesn't exist during T2's creation. At the end, all of them are valid:

```
SQL> select object_name, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3')
  4    and object_type = 'TRIGGER';

OBJECT_NAME          STATUS
-------------------- -------
T3                   VALID
T2                   VALID
T1                   VALID

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, regarding AFTER STARTUP triggers]**

I created triggers in SYS schema, similar to those 3 I posted previously:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger t1
  2  after startup on database
  3  begin
  4    insert into test values (1);
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger t2
  2  after startup on database
  3  follows t3
  4  begin
  5    insert into test values (2);
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> create or replace trigger t3
  2  after startup on database
  3  follows t1
  4  begin
  5    insert into test values (3);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Shut my XE down, started it up, checked what's in there:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select * From test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Blah! Really, it doesn't work as I thought it would.

Oh well, I was wrong & apologize to all of you.

Comment: That's new to me. Never used that before. >>     follows t3

Comment: We are dealing with startup database triggers

Comment: the FOLLOWS clause says... "must be defined on the same table"

Comment: No objections to that, Ed; feel free to continue doing so. I thought you asked how to "order" execution of multiple triggers, so I told you - use the FOLLOWS keyword. What makes you think it won't work in AFTER STARTUP triggers? They are just *triggers*, after all.

Comment: Though, after testing a little bit more, it seems that I was wrong. It doesn't work as I hoped it would. Sorry, ED & @Kris. It seems that you'll have to find another way to run your procedures in a desired order.

Comment: why not just have your trigger fire a procedure which then calls the procedures you want, in the order you want?